# Active directory lookup in Angular 7

Tags: c#, angular, active-directory, angular7

I am using an input search field in angular reactive form as look up for AD users. So, when you start typing your name, you should get some auto complete options for the field. For this i am calling a web api method from my angular app which in turn returning me a list of users. I am binding that list of users to the input field data list. I am using following code in my web api:-

```
 public List<string> ADUsers()
 {
    List<string> users = new List<string>();  
    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "abc.in"))
    {
      using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
      {
         foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
         {
            DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
            if(de.Properties["givenName"].Value != null && de.Properties["sn"].Value != null)
              users.Add(de.Properties["givenName"].Value + " " + de.Properties["sn"].Value);
         }
       }
     }
     return users;
 }
```

As the number of users is too much, It is taking time to return the list to angular(20-25 secs) which in return taking time to reflect in reactive form input field. I am new to angular and basically a .net developer. Could you suggest some way to figure out some responsive solution? or could it be possible to have the functionality in angular itself so that i should not call web api method for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple problems I see in your code:

1. You are not filtering users. So this code is finding every single user in your domain every time you run it. You can change this by using the text the user has already typed as a filter, and by limiting the number of results returned (there is no point displaying 100+ names in an auto-complete control)
2. `PrincipalSearcher`, and the whole `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace is not very efficient. For example, in this case, it is loading every attribute for every result found behind the scenes, even though you are only using the first and last name. You can do better by using the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace directly (`DirectorySearcher`/`DirectoryEntry`, which is what the `AccountManagement` namespace uses behind the scenes anyway).

Here is an example that should work in your case:

```
public List<string> ADUsers(string filter) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filter));

    List<string> users = new List<string>();
    var ds = new DirectorySearcher(
        new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://abc.in"), //domain to search
        $"(&(objectClass=user)(anr={filter}))", //search filter
        new[] { "givenName", "sn" }) //attributes to load
    {
        SizeLimit = 25 //change this depending on how many you want to show
    };

    using (var results = ds.FindAll()) {
        foreach (SearchResult result in results) {
            users.Add($"{result.Properties["givenName"][0]} {result.Properties["sn"][0]}");
        }
    }
    return users;
}
```

You can pass it any partial name as the `filter`, and it uses a feature in AD called [Ambiguous Name Resolution](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22653.active-directory-ambiguous-name-resolution.aspx) to find users. That will look for partial matches in the first name, last name, and other attributes (full list in that documentation).

I also limited the results to 25, but you can change that as you'd like.

This method also tells AD to *only* return the `givenName` and `sn` attributes for each result, since that's all we care about. That will lessen the amount of network traffic between your app and the domain controller.

Answer (score 0):

I have also done with applying filters in my approach and it is very fast. Code is given below: -

```
public List<string> ADUsers(string filter)
{
    List<string> users = new List<string>();

    PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "abc.in");
    UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(domainContext)
    {
        GivenName = filter + "*"
    };

    PrincipalSearcher pS = new PrincipalSearcher
    {
        QueryFilter = user
    };

    PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = pS.FindAll();
    List<Principal> pc = results.ToList();
    foreach (Principal p in pc)
    {
        DirectoryEntry de = (DirectoryEntry)p.GetUnderlyingObject();
        if (de.Properties["givenName"].Value != null && de.Properties["sn"].Value != null)
            users.Add(de.Properties["givenName"].Value + " " + de.Properties["sn"].Value);
    }

    return users;
}
```

I don't think using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement will have any performace issue and it is working perfectly for me. Still i marked Gabriel's answer as correct answer (idea for applying filter).